# Populate UITableViewCells with Core Data objects

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, core-data

### Introduction to my issue:

I am trying to figure out the best way to populate my custom UITableViewCells with information from Core Data.
What I've done up until now is to have a property of an NSManagedObject in the UITableViewCell subclass. In `configureCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` I pass the object to the cell and in the cell subclass I set up the cell with the objects properties. This is working very nicely but I have some random crashes when the managedObjectContext is updated and I am afraid it has to do with zombie objects in some of the cells. The cell itself is quite advanced with lots of information and to avoid duplicate code (setting the cell up in `cellForRow:atIndexPath:`) I configure the cell in the subclass itself. This is nice as I am using the same UITableViewCell subclass in both my application and in a TodayView extension. What is the best way to do what I described? Is my way 'bad'? I would love some input.
I will provide some simplified code below to describe the concept I am using.

### Simplified code for my UITableViewCell subclass:

```
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var iconImageView: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var mainTitleLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var subTitleLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var checkMarkImageView: UIImageView!

//Object is the NSManagedObject that is passed in at configureCell:atIndexPath
var objectForCell: Object? {
    didSet {

        if let object = objectForCell {

            //Main title
            if let title = object.title {
                mainTitleLabel.text = title
            }
            else {
                mainTitleLabel.text = "Title empty."
            }

            //Sub title
            if let subTitle = object.subTitle {
                subTitleLabel.text = subTitle
            }
            else {
                subTitleLabel.text = "Sub title empty."
            }

            //Icon image
            if let category = object.category {

                switch category {

                case .Car: iconImageView.image = UIImage(named: "car")

                case .Plane: iconImageView.image = UIImage(named: "plane")

                case .Boat: iconImageView.image = UIImage(named: "boat")

                default: iconImageView.image = UIImage(named: "unknown")
                }

            }
            else {
                iconImageView.image = UIImage(named: "unknown")
            }

            //Dot indication
            if let valid = object.valid {

                if valid == true {
                    checkMarkImageView.hidden = false
                }
                else {
                    checkMarkImageView.hidden = true
                }
            }
            else {
                checkMarkImageView.hidden = true
            }

        }

    }
}

}
```

### Simplified code for configureCell:atIndexPath: (called in cellForRow:):

```
class MyTableView : UITableView {

func configureCell(cell: MyTableViewCell, indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? Object {

        cell.objectForCell = object
    }
}

}
```

Here is the last part of the stack trace for the crash that normally happens:

```
2   
UIKit 0x00000001876475a4 -[UITableView    _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 540
3   
UIKit 0x000000018763c08c -[UITableView  _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2152
4   
UIKit 0x00000001874313cc -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 168
5   
UIKit 0x000000018734dd2c -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 568
```

Answer (score 0):

Although there is nothing seemingly wrong with your approach (and the crashes may be related to some other issue in your code), perhaps a better approach is using NSFetchedResultsController. Worthwhile to at least have a look if you are not aware of it.

Harry

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am already using a NSFetchedResultsController and the crash occurs when core data is updated. I will edit my post to include the last part of the stack trace in the crash report.